# R: xts package endpoints function does not support milliseconds on Windows

Tags: r, xts

I am trying to convert tick data to millisecond bars. I created a xts object and I was able to convert it to second and minute bars.

However, I discovered that `endpoints` does not support milliseconds on Windows.

```
endpoints(xts_tick,"milliseconds",100)
```

My question is: is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Can you please show what you tried, and point out what about the output you think is incorrect?